# Check if wordpress user is logged in via external script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to check if a user has logged into WordPress via an external script.

Wordpress is located in the /blog/ directory. The external script is on the homepage (/index.php)

The code below returns an empty array when I am logged in.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );   
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'blog/wp-load.php'; 
if ( !function_exists( 'is_user_logged_in' ) ) { 
    require_once    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php'; 
} 

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
    echo 'logged in';
}       

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
```

However this returns the following empty values:

```
Username: 
User email: 
User first name: 
User last name: 
User display name: 
User ID: 0
```

After a bit of research, I have also tried the following in the config file which did not help.

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.abc.com'); // your main domain
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('abc.com')); // notice absence of a '.' in front
```

Any ideas why it is not returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working. Make sure this is at the top of wp-config.php

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.xxxfff.com'); 
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('xxxfff.com')); 

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Front end script

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'blog/wp-load.php'; 
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//var_dump($current_user->ID);
//var_dump($current_user->display_name);
//var_dump($_COOKIE);


if ( !function_exists( 'is_user_logged_in' ) ) { 
    require_once    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php'; 
} 

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
    echo 'not logged in';
} else {
    // Logged in.
    echo 'logged in';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following script works fine.

```
include('/var/www/html/wp2/wp-load.php');
//var_dump($_COOKIE);

global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
var_dump($current_user->ID);
var_dump($current_user->display_name);
```

***you should put the script on your WordPress root folder***, then only WordPress can access the **$_COOKIE** and let you log in

More info for debugging:
First, try to print `$_COOKIE`

`var_dump($_COOKIE);`

And confirm your script can access the WordPress **$_COOKIE**

it will look something like this

```
array (size=5)
    'wordpress_test_cookie' => string 'WP Cookie check' (length=15)
    'wordpress_logged_in_xxx' => string 'xx|xx|xxx|xxx' (length=125)
    'wp-settings-time-1' => string '1513059194' (length=10)
    'io' => string 'xxx-xx' (length=20)
```

Comment: Thanks for your message, just tested in in the /blog/ directory and can confirm it works fine. Any idea how to access it outside of the /blog/ directory?

Comment: It will not work outside of your domain path because `$_COOKIE`'s scope won't work outside of domain

Comment: After checking the Core of WordPress they set the user info from cookies, so when your script is outside of the scope of the cookie, WordPress cannot access it so it forces to WP_User with ID 0.

Comment: There is a way if you want to get them,put an script (should send you all users info ) inside /blog dir , and you can make the request to that script.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I didn't realise this would be an issue!

Curious about your last point. I moved the script inside of the blog directory then made a request to it using require() (from /index.php), how it is still returning empty. Is there a better way to access this file to match the users cookie?

Comment: `require` won't help because the main script is you are running is outside of domain. I hope  ajax request would help

Comment: Please accept the answer if this fixes your problem, i can still reply for your comments to fix other issues

Comment: this could help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies
am not sure it works, but it would give you some idea